# How to open a new web page using mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to open new web page for exemple https://www.google.md/
I want to do this using @Html.ActionLink if it is possible, can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to do this using @Html.ActionLink if it is possible

`Html.ActionLink` should be used for internal urls that are part of the same application as it depends on routing.

If you want to generate a link to an external url you could use a normal anchor element:

```
<a href="https://www.google.md/">Go to google</a>
```

Comment: real problem is: I have country city, posta code and I must to open it in maps.google.com can you help me please?

Comment: You could pass parameters to this url in a query string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open it in new browser page use also `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="https://www.google.md/" target="_blank">Google!</a>
```

but if you want just to open another web site's url with some value frome your code you can do it like:

```
<a href="https://www.google.md/index.php?somevalue="+@myvalue+" target="_blank">Google!</a>
```